# Comparing Views in onCreateContextMenu

Tags: android, view, contextmenu

I have an activity with an `EditText` box and a `ListView`.  I also `Override` `onCreateContextMenu` like this:

```
@Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        android.view.MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.comments_context, menu);
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Available Actions");

        Log.d("v: ", String.valueOf(v));

        MenuItem Edit = menu.findItem(R.id.editComment);
        MenuItem Delete = menu.findItem(R.id.deleteComment);

        AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;


        int position = info.position;
        ListView lv = (ListView) v;
        int firstVisible = lv.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        View rowView = lv.getChildAt(position - firstVisible);

        ReviewUser = ((TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.labelReviewCommentUser)).getText()
                .toString();

        ReviewComment = ((TextView) rowView                 .findViewById(R.id.labelReviewComment)).getText().toString();
```

Here is problem.  `onCreateContext` can be called by system when I longpress an `EditText` box for cut/copy/paste/etc.  It also can be called when you long click my `ListView`.  I get a null crash at the Two TextViews at the bottom's above in last line when system calls onCreateContextMenu from `EditText`.

Here is solution:  I need to compare views when `onCreateConextMenu` is created.  However, i do not know how to do this and can't find solution anywhere.  I have Logg'ed View v, and all other views in my activity and it ALWAYS points to my `ListView`...

How can I create code that says:

```
         if (view passed in is from ListView) {


            MenuItem Edit = menu.findItem(R.id.editComment);
            MenuItem Delete = menu.findItem(R.id.deleteComment);

                // do other things

          }
```

Can anyone guide me? I've been looking for a week on this...

Comment: In one place, you claim "onCreateContext can be called by system when I longpress an EditText box for cut/copy/paste/etc". In another place, you claim "I have Logg'ed View v, and all other views in my activity and it ALWAYS points to my ListView". Those statements cannot both be true.

Comment: @CommonsWare How can I explain this? I `Log.d` `View v` (as a String value of course) and when I long press the EditText, get the normal nullpointer crash, check `View v` (in LogCat), and it says `android.widget.ListView@4183da90`.  Why is the `ListView` being passed in?  I didn't touch the `ListView`? -- A thought comes to my mind, the `EditText` box is in the header of my `ListView`, would that make a difference?

Comment: That's interesting-- I certainly would not expect a header view to behave that way. On a tangentially-related note, try doing `super.onCreateContextMenu(...)` last, after the rest of your work.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for the help.. sadly same result.

Comment: Oh, yeah, never mind, I misunderstood what you were doing. My best recommendation is to get the `EditText` out of the header view. I've never been a fan of having `EditText` widgets in `ListView` rows to begin with.

Comment: @Commonsware I moved the `EditText` OUT of the `ListView` header and into the main layout and that fixed it.. just for your reference

Comment: @CommonsWare I actually don't have `EditText` in the actual rows.. just in the header itself. Practical application: Users make comments in the header up top and then the comment drops to the list below. Now the app looks more like Google+ with comment field stickied to the bottom (not the footer). Feel free to write the answer and I'll mark it correct.

Comment: I'm not sure we *have* an answer, other than `ListView` may have what I'd consider to be a bug. I'll try to run some tests on this scenario someday and will perhaps file a bug report.

Comment: FWIW, I was able to reproduce the problem on Android 2.3 and have filed an issue on it: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=51854

Comment: @CommonsWare Glad I wasn't going insane on that.  I had another Activity/Fragment were I faced the same challenge and I just used the workaround... so at least there is options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the final solution, because what was happening may actually be a bug, but simply moving the `EditText` out of the `ListView` header but to the main XML file allowed me to bypass the issue.